# Does it matter what order I do the missions on Tuchanka in?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm orbiting Tuchanka, and there are several missions available to me, does it matter what order I do them in?

Comment: It is generally a good idea to put off Priority missions as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put off the priority mission there, and make sure you rescue the Turian squad as early as possible.  This will open up another mission (Tuchanka: Bomb) that I've been told is [time sensitive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53841/are-there-time-limited-objectives-in-the-game), so once you've rescued the squad, take care of it quickly!

The other mission is one of the [N7 missions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54714/13845) vs. Cerberus, and I don't believe it's time sensitive, but I took care of it before rescuing the Turian squad, with no penalty to the Turian squad missions.

Answer (score 2):

The only one that matters is if you start the [**Turian rescue**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Tuchanka:_Turian_Platoon) mission.  This is because afterwards, you will be on a "timer", being given the Bomb mission, which, if you do 3 missions before tackling this one, it will count as a failure.

[**source**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Tuchanka:_Bomb)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. The Tuchanka Bomb mission is highly time critical and should be completed at first opportunity. All other missions can be done at your leisure. Word of warning however is that if you complete ALL the Priority Tuchanka missions before completing all the ACT 1 Citadel side missions AND the Grissom Academy mission, you'll get locked out of those as the Citadel will come under attack. Other than that, you're free to pick and choose.

Answer (score 0):

You really really should do the N7 mission and get the Improved Power Grid there, then go back to the Citadel to turn it in to the girl by the Purgatory bar. If you don't, the mission will be stuck as incomplete (assuming you picked it up in the first place).